# phpMyAdmin: import button not available

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have to move a Wordpress Website from my server to the Client server. I exported the database from my phpMYAdmin but Actually when i tried to import the Database on the Client's phpMyAdmin the "import" button is not available. I can only Export...

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the content of the SQL file, past it in the SQL box and run the SQL Script.